# toggleClass() from jquery not working for a valid selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, onmouseover

My hide class does not accept the toggleClass:

```
function overFx (element, classN) {

    if (!element.hasClass('ligado')){

        if (!$.browser.webkit && !$.browser.opera){
            //TR

            element.toggleClass(classN);

        } else {
            //TD

            element.children("td:not(.media)").toggleClass(classN);
        }
    }
}
//EFEITOS PARA DESTACAR LINHAS:

//MOUSE OVER:

$("tr.destacar:not(.hide)").mouseover(function (){

    overFx($(this), "mouseoverTr");
}
);

$(".hide").mouseover(function (){

    overFx($(this), "mouseoverTrHide");
}
);

//MOUSE OUT:

$("tr.destacar:not(.hide)").mouseout(function (){

    overFx($(this), "mouseoverTr");
}
);

$(".hide").mouseover(function (){

    overFx($(this), "mouseoverTrHide");
}
);
```

I'll post the Jsfiddle later.

The `$("tr.destacar:not(.hide)")` par is working perfectly, but the  `$(".hide")` isn't , and it should be! they are there , I console.logged it , the `$(this)` returns exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. can you console.log `this` after `overFx` to confirm that it isn't getting/losing the class it is supposed to?

Comment: I did , its perfect... I really can't see a thing wrong , but it simply just doesn't work!

Comment: so the class is toggling properly, but you aren't seeing the difference visually?

Comment: worse , just the selected tr.hide class is NOT toggling , the other class - .mouseoverTrHide - is never appearing in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `$(".hide").mouseout(...)` method, you have `.mouseover(...)` instead.

To re-iterate, you have `$(".hide").mouseover` twice, where the second one should be a `.mouseout` instead.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ducYE/

Comment: Sweet mother of Jesus Christ, dude , 3 programmers at the office couldn't get that and you caught it , points for you, negative for our stupidity. Thanks!

Comment: Trust me, it was VERY hard to catch. hahaha. I caught it by changing the .hide class to .hided, and forgot to change it at the bottom resulting in it halfway working.